# Update/Insert/Delete on a particular database table

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm updating a solution that I wrote a while ago. I've got a WinForm that does Update/Insert/Delete on a particular database table.

I've got all of the database access code in the form. Is this bad practise? On the one hand, I know you should separate presentation and data access. Also, it would make unit testing easier. On the other hand, it would be quite complex to separate and, the way it is, I find it quite easy to follow when I come back to it after a while.

```
namespace Investments_4
{
public partial class Form5 : Form
{
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = ""C:\Users\Nick\Documents\Investments 4.mdf""; Integrated Security = True; Connect Timeout = 30");
SqlCommand myCommand;
SqlDataAdapter myAdapter;
int ID = 0;

public Form5()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //PopulateLastValData();
    DisplayData();
}

private void DisplayData()
{
    myConnection.Open();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    String portName = Variables.valPort;
    myAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select Id, movementDate, portfolio, movement from Movement WHERE (portfolio = @SQLName) ORDER BY movementDate DESC", myConnection);
    myAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@SQLName", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    myAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters["@SQLName"].Value = Variables.valPort;
    myAdapter.Fill(dt);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Name";
    dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Date";
    dataGridView1.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Movement";
    dataGridView1.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
    dataGridView1.Columns[3].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "C";
    myConnection.Close();
}

//Clear Data  
private void ClearData()
{
    textBox2.Text = "";
    ID = 0;
}

private void Form5_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{



}

private void label4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void button_Insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox2.Text != "")
    {
        myCommand = new SqlCommand("insert into Movement (movementDate,portfolio,movement) values(@date,@name,@value)", myConnection);
        myConnection.Open();
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", dateTimePicker1.Value);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", Variables.valPort);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", textBox2.Text);
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myConnection.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Record Inserted Successfully");
        DisplayData();
        ClearData();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Provide Details!");
    }
}

private void button_Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ID != 0)
    {
        myCommand = new SqlCommand("delete Movement where Id=@id", myConnection);
        myConnection.Open();
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ID);
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myConnection.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Record Deleted Successfully!");
        DisplayData();
        ClearData();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Select Record to Delete");
    }
}

private void dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    ID = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
    textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
}

private void button_Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox2.Text != "")
    {
        myCommand = new SqlCommand("update Movement set portfolio = @name, movementDate=@date, movement=@movement where Id=@id", myConnection);
        myConnection.Open();
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ID);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", dateTimePicker1.Value);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@movement", textBox2.Text);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", Variables.valPort);
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Record Updated Successfully");
        myConnection.Close();
        DisplayData();
        ClearData();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Select Record to Update");
    }
}

private void button_back_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> Should I separate out data access code in a Winform?

I can answer you question with your own words:

> - I know you should separate presentation and data access.
> - Also, it would make unit testing easier.

---

> On the other hand, it would be quite complex to separate and, the way it is,

It won't be any more complex then it already is and you'll be able to verify many parts of your application without having to click every button and hoping it won't crash.

> I find it quite easy to follow when I come back to it after a while.

It is not easy to follow and you won't know how it works or what it does because the names are really messy and when you see the code in a while you'll be asking:

- `myConnection` - connection with what?
- `myAdapter` - adapter for what?
- `dataGridView1` - grid view for what?
- `button_Insert_Click` - insert what?
- `textBox2` - text-box for what?
- `MessageBox.Show("Please Provide Details!");` - what details?
- `int ID = 0;` - id of what?
- `Form5` - a form for what?
- `label4_Click(..)` - why isn't this one implemented (yet/anymore)?

You know you should separate it so do it. You know you'll need the names later so use meainingful names for **everything**.

Answer (score 4):

### Unnecessary event handler

You have some unused event handlers:

```
void Form5_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
void label4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

If you don't know how to remove them, you can access the events list of a `Control` in the design view on the properties tab and than  pressing the lightning icon, find the event there and remove it:

[image]

### `Int.Parse()` vs `Convert.ToInt32()`

If you are sure that your conversion value will be of type string you should use `Int.Parse()`, `Convert.ToInt32()` is mostly used when you are converting an `object` to `int`.

### `using` statement vs manually closing SQL connecton

You shouldn't open and close connections manually, you should instead use the `using statement` which disposes all the memory when your program is about to exit the body.

Your code with manual opening/closing of connection:

> ```
> myCommand =
>     new SqlCommand(
>         "update Movement set portfolio = @name, movementDate=@date, movement=@movement where Id=@id",
>         myConnection);
> myConnection.Open();
> myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ID);
> myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", dateTimePicker1.Value);
> myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@movement", textBox2.Text);
> myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", Variables.valPort);
> myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
> MessageBox.Show("Record Updated Successfully");
> myConnection.Close();
> ```

With the `using` statement:

```
using (myCommand =
    new SqlCommand(
        "update Movement set portfolio = @name, movementDate=@date, movement=@movement where Id=@id",
        myConnection))
{
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ID);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", dateTimePicker1.Value);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@movement", textBox2.Text);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", Variables.valPort);
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Record Updated Successfully");
}
```

Comment: Does int.Parse support converting from various bases? Because last I checked, it doesn't -- so if you need to convert between hex string and int, you need to use Convert.

Comment: I'd go with `Convert.ToInt32` if I have different base numbers in the string but I'm assuming OP is working with decimal numbers.

Comment: Oh, whoops. Misread the original code.